# Unit testing spring webservice client Classes Inheriting WebServiceGatewaySupport

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to unit test a webservice client in Spring boot. My client extends `WebServiceGatewaySupport` class and I am using **Mockito** framework.

The issue is I am unable to mock the super class method `getWebServiceMethod`

A quick search only explains about Integration test using spring which is not what I need [[link]](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-ws-client-side-integration-testing/)

in S/O it has been suggested to Mock the entire base class, but its not  possible either since the unit tests are in same package and also I dont want to manually mock a spring class.

I understand `composition over inheritance` but is this a valid use case for violating this and How do we achieve this unit testing in these cases?

Comment: Have you considered using a spy object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the springboot internal tomcat using @AutoConfigureMockMvc

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
// plus some other that I skip for sake of simplicity


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StandaloneApplication.class) // StandaloneClass is where you call SpringApplication.run
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DictionaryControllerTest  {
   private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   @Test
   public void createDictionary() throws Exception {
       Cookies cookies;  // add cookies if you need
       String body; // add a body if you need
       MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = requestBuilder(post("/dictionaries"), body, cookies);
       ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(request);
       // you can also extract the content
       CollectionDocument dictionary = mapper.readValue(resultActions.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), CollectionDocument.class);
       // then do the test
       Assert.assertNotNull(dictionary.getId());
   }
```